# How to replace all instances of a character except the last n instances in each line of a file in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, character

I have a file with a few dozen lines.

e.g.

```
Vector volume solid option displays (beta version) added to OpenGL Volume (2/22/18).
Up to 6 unique sitemap bitmap option added to the OpenGL Volume display (2/19/18).
Import of Vector-xyza.dat file min/max values on location adjusted to the lower and upper integral values (2/19/18).
```

I need to retain the date and the brackets around the date at the end of each line. But, as in the first line, sometimes brackets are used elsewhere. I need to replace those brackets with e.g. a dash.

The ideal output would be:

```
Vector volume solid option displays -beta version- added to OpenGL Volume (2/22/18).
Up to 6 unique sitemap bitmap option added to the OpenGL Volume display (2/19/18).
Import of Vector-xyza.dat file min/max values on location adjusted to the lower and upper integral values (2/19/18).
```

How can I do this in a bash script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are expected to add what you tried to question as well... hover mouse over the downvote button..

Comment: @Sundeep, I Googled extensively before asking the question here, but couldn't find a suitable solution. Do you expect me to list all the inappropriate Google search results?

Comment: hope you take it positive note.. in such cases, I'd at least highlight that point in question and make some attempt with sed/awk.. like even a simple `sed 's/[()]/-/g'` .. it'd help to show your efforts done.. tagging `grep` means you are just throwing tags around.. grep is for finding text, it cannot modify..

Comment: Point taken about grep; I have removed that tag.

Comment: However, your other point about including that sed example doesn't make sense. I would never have tried that command, because it doesn't do what is needed. So why should I include it in the OP as something I tried, when I would not and did not try such?

Comment: that was meant as an example.. include *something* in whatever way to show efforts from your end.. I'll avoid extended discussion and leave this link instead https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users (see all answers, not just accepted one)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple **`sed`** approach:

```
sed -E 's/\(([^0-9()]+[^()]+)\)/-\1-/g' file
```

The output:

```
Vector volume solid option displays -beta version- added to OpenGL Volume (2/22/18).
Up to 6 unique sitemap bitmap option added to the OpenGL Volume display (2/19/18).
Import of Vector-xyza.dat file min/max values on location adjusted to the lower and upper integral values (2/19/18).
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

So this is just quick and dirty, but you get the idea:

```
echo 'Vector volume solid option displays (beta version) added to OpenGL Volume (2/22/18).' | sed -En 's/\(([a-zA-Z])/-\1/p' | sed -nE 's/([a-zA-Z])\)/\1-/p'
Vector volume solid option displays -beta version- added to OpenGL Volume (2/22/18).
```

First sed replaces left bracket if followed by a letter, next sed replaces brackets if following a letter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't help me as I need to run it as part of a script, with variable text within it. @RomanPerekhrest's answer solves the problem though. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe '
    $l = tr/(//; $r = tr/)//;
    die "Different number of left ($l) and right ($r) brackets.\n"
        if $l != $r;
    s/\(/-/,s/\)/-/ while --$l;
' -- file
```

Comment: Thanks, choroba. I'm not sure if this works for me specifically... I have no experience using perl, but am familiar with sed, so I have opted for @RomanPerekhrest's solution instead. (I'm not saying your solution doesn't work, just that I haven't tried it, and I'm just noting this for future readers...).

Thanks for the suggestion nonetheless. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have (5 beta version), you can try this sed

```
sed -E ':A;s/([^(]*)(\()([^)]*)(\))([^(]*)(\([^)]*\).*)/\1-\3-\5\6/;tA' infile
```